# Problems defining two services in modules

Tags: angularjs

I try to define angular services of an angular module in serperate files.
While Chrome only mentions an Uncaught Object, Firefox throws this message:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=LaRa&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.9%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DLaRa%0AF%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F
```

This tells me nothing. See my [jsfiddle failing here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sa95B/1/).

I looked up the "recommended Setup" article in the [angularjs documentation for modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module). When i copy their example to my jsfiddle i get the same error. [see jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sa95B/2/).

Their [plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/lKC4eisJXx6qJwHTxUPh?p=preview) works thou.

Now jsfiddle includes the javascript inline, plunkr uses a file and there are certain other differences. Sure. But is that really it?
I never read anything about angularjs only working if you put your javascript in an external file.

If i copy from their tutorial, it should work instead of giving a weird error shouldn't it?
What am i doing wrong here?

---

**EDIT:** 
If i change from onLoad to wrap-in-head [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/Sa95B/6/). Yet i do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected when you actually attach the angularjs 1.2.1 in head

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  {{ greeting1.value }}!
  {{ greeting2.value }}!
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sa95B/4/

Comment: i did add angular (1.2.9) as an external recource in the jsfiddle.
that's why i got an angular specific error message.

Comment: You did change from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>` which is what made the difference.

Comment: I don't think it ever worked for me onLoad, although plnkr is better IMHO, you should give it a go

Comment: And why the changes with .value? how does that change anything?

Comment: Sorry that's just a habit to have a dot in model - "if you don't have a dot you are doing somthing wrong" ;)

Comment: :D Joker! I ment: Why did you change from assigning the model rather than the value and pointed that out in your answer. Has nothing to do with solving the problem right?

Comment: Yes, it has nothing to do with the answer, it's just that I do a lot of two-way data binding between controllers/services and thats just habit to write it that way for me